# CKEditor - Integration into best_in_place gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I implemented https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails into my application and want to further implement this into a best_in_place textarea.

application.js

```
$('.ckeditor').ckeditor({
    // optional config
});
```

view.html.erb

```
<%= best_in_place @post, :body, :as => :textarea, class: 'ckeditor',  inner_class: 'ckeditor form-control', ok_button: 'Update', ok_button_class: 'btn btn-outline-success btn-sm', raw: true%>
```

This doesn't work.

If I do something like this:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :body, class: 'ckeditor'%>
<% end %>
```

it works, but I want it inside my best_in_place textarea.

I want the inline ckeditor version implemented in my project. I don't want to replace the textarea with the ckeditor area, I just want the toolbar for my existing textarea.

```
 <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
        <% if current_user == @post.user || current_user.try(:admin?) %>
          <%= best_in_place @post, :body, :as => :textarea, class: 'ckeditor',  inner_class: 'ckeditor form-control', ok_button: 'Update', ok_button_class: 'btn btn-outline-success btn-sm', raw: true%>
        <% else %>
        <p class="postbody"><%= sanitize @post.body %></p>
          <% end %>
        <div class="py-3">
```

Answer (score 0):

the thing here is that the textarea is generated dynamically, so you need to run the initialization of ckeditor after the textarea is there, something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.best_in_place').bind('best_in_place:activate', function(){
    alert("hey it's working");
    $('.ckeditor').ckeditor({
      // optional config
    });
  });
});
```

on the activation of the textarea, you initialize the ckeditor, of course, is better to bind this to just the one you want with the ckeditor, so it doesn't run the init of the editor on every input.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Stays as textarea. BTW: Is there any way of implementing this https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_inline.html? I think it would be better if I just have my normal form-control class and display the WYSIWYG editor above it

Comment: already tested it on local and works like a charm, just be sure to put the code inside a document ready

Comment: I tried it with the code above, but I can't get it to work somehow. My editor sticks with the same view. I'll update my answer and provide some code.

Comment: Ok, at least you receive the alert?

Comment: I do recieve the alert, yes. It pops up and after clicking OK it it opens the best_in_place field, without the ckeditor.

Comment: Can you inspect the textarea after showing, to see if it have the class ckeditor? And remove the class from the input code, and let ckeditor just in the inner_class part

Comment: I got it to work now, but I can't see it since once it opens it directly closes afterwards.

Comment: Well, we solved the problem, if it closes directly then it's maybe conflict with another code

Comment: Yes, probably is. But still, this is the complete editor. Is there any way of providing only the toolbar? Just like here : https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/#inline

Comment: in that case, you need to create a custom toolbar and specify it for your field. see the documentation for this
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_toolbar.html

Comment: remember how stackoverflow works, create complete questions and if you have more specific details, create a new one for that purpose